# What is the purpose of intent data in android clipboard?

Tags: android, android-intent

Can anyone tell me what is the purpose of intent data in android clipboard.
Also, how can we paste intent data present in clipboard to any where in the system.
Any suggestions or references would be appreciated.
Please refer the following link:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html

The Purpose of intent here is not clarified. How to use intent for creating application shortcuts that are then placed in the system's clipboard for further use by the app ??
 Thanks in advance

Comment: It is unclear what question you are asking. Please edit your question and clarify what you mean.

Comment: Intent data is a means for passing arguments to a intent. The actual meaning of the data will differ from intent to intent. Unsure why it would need to be on the clipboard.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please go through the document. It specifies three types of data out of which plain text and uri can be placed on the clipboard using clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip but how to put intent data on the global clipboard. What is it's use/purpose ?